# How to print array elements if the array is getting updated dynamically in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @logsfiles = `tail -f /var/logs/*.log`;

foreach my $log (@logfiles){
     print $log;
}
```

I am using above mentioned snippet in my script, i want to know a method where i can print array entries on the go! as my tail -f command gives output dynamically.

Help is much appreciated.
Best regards,
Shantesh

Comment: The array isn't "getting updated dynamically". The first line of code won't finish running until the `tail` command exits, and then it will contain all the lines it ever printed.

Comment: @hobbs
I did try this
`print @logsfiles = tail -f /var/logs/*.log` and it prints the partial output such as tail: /var/icc_shantesh/logs/repcoll.log: Stale NFS file handle
not the content which got modifed !

Comment: That's an error output, which is printed directly to the terminal and not captured by the backticks at all. You need to understand the difference between stdout and stderr.

Comment: @hobbs 
Thanks for informing can you let me know how to get the actuall modified data from above mentioned script ?

Answer (score 3):

There's an example of how to use File::Tail on multiple files here:   https://metacpan.org/source/MGRABNAR/File-Tail-1.3/select_demo

Comment: Any simpler approach ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(my $tail_pipe,'tail -f /var/logs/*.log |');

while(my $line = <$tail_pipe>) {
    print $line;
}

close($tail_pipe);
```

Comment: Thanks 

some how i am not getting the complete content on the terminal!, i am only getting
     tail: /var/icc_shantesh/logs/repcoll.log: Stale NFS file handle
     tail: /var/icc_shantesh/logs/repcoll.log: Stale NFS file handle
     tail: `/varicc_shantesh/logs/repcoll.log' has become accessible
     tail: `/var/icc_shantesh/logs/repcoll.log' has become accessible

where i made some changes in the entries in the file 

Not sure how to get that as well on terminal.

Comment: how to print the actual output ?

Comment: @Shantesh what actual output? change the command to get the output you desire.

Comment: above mentioned script should print all the updated information from the file on the terminal that is what i am after and in the above mentioned answer by hobbs he mentioned that i should know about STDOUT and STDERR how to get the STDOUT rather than STDERR on screen ?